# Loop using Search in Google Sheet and Google Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

As of now I have a function that I can call anytime I want and now Im calling it in 'onLoad' and here is the code.

HTML File

```
<table  id = "TableContainer" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" width ="100%" align = "center" class="hoverTable">
   <tr>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen"><font color="white">#</font></th>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen"><font color="white">Area</font></th>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen" width = "200px"><font color="white">Customer Name</font></th>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen"><font color="white">Person In Charge</font></th>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen" width = "250px"><font color="white">Remarks</font></th>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen"><font color="white">Status</font></th>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen"><font color="white">Doc. Date</font></th>
   <th  bgcolor = "darkgreen"></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   </tr>
</table>
```

here is the javascript.

```
<script>
function GenerateTable() {
   <? var data = getData(); ?>  
   var table = document.getElementById("TableContainer");

   <? for (var i = 12; i < data.length; i++) { ?>


      var row = table.insertRow(-1);
      var row_did = row.insertCell(0);
      var row_area = row.insertCell(1);
      var row_cusname = row.insertCell(2);
      var row_pic = row.insertCell(3);
      var row_remarks = row.insertCell(4);
      var row_status = row.insertCell(5);
      var row_docudate = row.insertCell(6);
      var row_button = row.insertCell(7);

      row_did.innerHTML =      '<td  id="dataid" class="dataid">'+ <?= data[i][0] ?> + '</td>';
      row_area.innerHTML =     '<td  id="area" class="area">'+ <?= data[i][1] ?> +'<td>';
      row_cusname.innerHTML =  '<td  id ="cusname" class="cusname">' + <?= data[i][2] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_pic.innerHTML =      '<td  id ="cic" class="cic">' + <?= data[i][3] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_remarks.innerHTML =  '<td  id ="remarks" class="remarks">' + <?= data[i][4] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_status.innerHTML =   '<td  id ="status" class="status">' +<?= data[i][5] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_docudate.innerHTML = '<td  id ="docdate" class="docdate">'+ <?= data[i][6] ?>  +'<td>';
      row_button.innerHTML =   '<td><img id = "selectdata" class = "click-to-select" src= "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0By6kUPbaVMWCbUI0LTJTR2g2N3M" alt="Submit" width="13px" height="13px" title = "Edit Selected Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/></td>';
  <? } ?>

  $('.click-to-select').click(function() {

    var dataid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(1)').text()
    var area = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(2)').text();
    var cusname = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(3)').text();
    var cicoption = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(4)').text();
    var remarks = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(5)').text();
    var statoption = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(6)').text();
    var documentdate = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(7)').text();
        console.log('The dataid is:' + dataid)
    $('#dataid').val(dataid)
    $('#areaoption').val(area)
    $('#cusname').val(cusname)
    $('#cicoption').val(cicoption)
    $('#remarks').val(remarks)
    $('#statoption').val(statoption)
    $('#documentdate').val(documentdate)

});
}
</script>
```

and this is the google script.

```
function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
   .getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Customer Logs Information Database")
   .getDataRange()
   .getValues();
   return htmlTemplate;
}
```

Here is my question. I am trying to add this code in my `for loop`

`if (data[][]== "My Criteria")` so I will loop data based on my condition now my target is how can I use textbox value for that?

```
<input id="input_cusname" style="width: 200px;" name="input_cusname" type="text" />
```

Please take note Im using JavaScript and especially Google Script with tags **< ?? >**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with out using scriplet in javascript. The same thing can be achieved using `google.script.run`. It is also mentioned in [App script best practice documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices) to load data asynchronously and not via scriplet.

If you use the below code, remove the onload event from body tag.

```
<script>

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(GenerateTable).getData();

function GenerateTable(data) {
   console.log(data)
   var table = document.getElementById("TableContainer");

  for (var i = 12; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[][]== "My Criteria"){ //add your condition

      var row = table.insertRow(-1);
      var row_did = row.insertCell(0);
      var row_area = row.insertCell(1);
      var row_cusname = row.insertCell(2);
      var row_pic = row.insertCell(3);
      var row_remarks = row.insertCell(4);
      var row_status = row.insertCell(5);
      var row_docudate = row.insertCell(6);
      var row_button = row.insertCell(7);

      row_did.innerHTML =      '<td  id="dataid" class="dataid">'+ data[i][0]  + '</td>';
      row_area.innerHTML =     '<td  id="area" class="area">'+ data[i][1]  +'<td>';
      row_cusname.innerHTML =  '<td  id ="cusname" class="cusname">' + data[i][2]   +'<td>';
      row_pic.innerHTML =      '<td  id ="cic" class="cic">' + data[i][3]   +'<td>';
      row_remarks.innerHTML =  '<td  id ="remarks" class="remarks">' + data[i][4]   +'<td>';
      row_status.innerHTML =   '<td  id ="status" class="status">' +data[i][5]   +'<td>';
      row_docudate.innerHTML = '<td  id ="docdate" class="docdate">'+ data[i][6]   +'<td>';
      row_button.innerHTML =   '<td><img id = "selectdata" class = "click-to-select" src= "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0By6kUPbaVMWCbUI0LTJTR2g2N3M" alt="Submit" width="13px" height="13px" title = "Edit Selected Data" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/></td>';
   }
}
  $('.click-to-select').click(function() {

    var dataid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(1)').text()
    var area = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(2)').text();
    var cusname = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(3)').text();
    var cicoption = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(4)').text();
    var remarks = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(5)').text();
    var statoption = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(6)').text();
    var documentdate = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-of-type(7)').text();
        console.log('The dataid is:' + dataid)
    $('#dataid').val(dataid)
    $('#areaoption').val(area)
    $('#cusname').val(cusname)
    $('#cicoption').val(cicoption)
    $('#remarks').val(remarks)
    $('#statoption').val(statoption)
    $('#documentdate').val(documentdate)

});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sir Ritz. Tysm for helping again. Its Google Script sir and Im trying to pass textbox value here based on your code it seems that this is not what i needed.

Comment: Its Google script code only...I have added the documentation link too. If possible share the copy of your script and spreadhsheet and then I can help you then.

Comment: Sir Ritz for one more time can you please help me again? I will post another question. pls really not the same as this

Comment: sir how can i run it? call it in body load and onclick?

Comment: Put `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(GenerateTable).getData();` inside the script tag(not under any function).  It will run when js loads.

Comment: how about when I press a button? because I will pass data to the condition so it will show data based on what i want.

Comment: in that case, call it onclick event

Comment: like how sir? like this? onClick = "What will I add"?

Comment: Please continue this in chat

Comment: sorry sir no unable hehe